# When app's process is killed by closing recent apps, broadcast reciever is getting unregistered

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

In my app i am trying to do something when an outgoing call is made. For the purpose I registered a braodcast reciever with action as ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL. It works perfectly but when I kill application by recent apps drawer, no more broadcasts are recieved by App. How to re register Broadcast.
here is my code:
In braodcast reciever:

```
@Override 
   public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.mContext = context;

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
        number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        o_GetLocation = new GetLocation(context);
        Location location = o_GetLocation.getLocation();
        String lat = null;
        String longitutde = null;
        if (null != location) {
            lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            longitutde = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        }
        String msg =  "Called number: " + number + ", IMEI: " + getImei() + " Lat:"+lat +  " Long:" + longitutde;
        Log.d("TAG",msg);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, 200).show();
    }

    if (intent.getAction().equals("restartservice")) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class));
        Log.d("TAG", "restart");
    }
```

in service:

```
      @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    Log.d("TAG", "service oncreate");
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments");
    thread.start();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("TAG", "service started");
    BroadcastRec reciever = new BroadcastRec();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("restartservice");
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    registerReceiver(reciever, intentFilter);
    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // We don't provide binding, so return null
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("TAG", "service destroy");
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("restartservice"));
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.d("TAG", "service onTaskRemoved");
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("restartservice"));

}
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
    startService(intent);

}
```

}

Comment: register u r reciver in AndroidManifest.xml file itself

Comment: i tried..but same results

Comment: Well receiver registered in Manifest file can only be unregistered by PackageManager. Check if smthng is goin wrong.

Comment: It is working fine if i am not closing app from recent apps drawer, but in this case i am not receiving further broadcasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to Permission manager, where Autostart is denied for my app. Thats why after clearing app from recent Broadcast recievers too was not working.

Comment: Can you please write more details?